# In VS Code, is it possible to execute keybinds based on the context of the line, or characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, if I'm writing something like this:

```
vector<int> v(10);

v[2<cursor is here>]
```

Is there some kind of when clause to add to custom keybinds, i.e., something along these lines:

```
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus && cursorNextChar == ']'"
}
```

And if nothing like that is built-in, what's a straightforward way to go about creating an extension that provides keybind extention customizability that executes commands based on the context of the line/characters around the cursor?

I tried using !atEndofWord but that breaks a lot of things like autocomplete and having tabs work as expected when not inside brackets.

Comment: I will try to add `cursorNextChar` to the extension [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context) so you can use it in `when` clauses to compare, if you have other ideas of tests you want add them to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context) (v0.4.0) fills the context variable `extraContext:editorCursorNextChar` with the character after the active position (cursor) of the first selection. The context variable is the empty string when the position is at the end of a line.

For your example set this key binding:

```json
  {
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "textInputFocus && extraContext:editorCursorNextChar == ']'"
  }
```